# Get a value of attached property from string name

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there any simple way to get a value of attached property in UWP? 
For instance I have a `TextBlock` defined in XAML:

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="TextBlock"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="MyTextBlockId"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Text="My Text Block" />
```

If I want to get a value of property `Text` from string property name, I can use reflection:

```
TextBlock.GetType().GetProperty("Text").GetValue(TextBlock);
```

What about attached properties? How can I access attached properties `Grid.Row` or `AutomationProperties.AutomationId` based on their string "names"?

Of course I can do following:

```
AutomationProperties.GetAutomationId(TextBlock);
Grid.GetRow(TextBlock);
```

but I would like to use something like:

```
TextBlock.GetProperty("AutomationProperties.GetAutomationId");
TextBlock.GetProperty("Grid.Row");
```

**UPDATE**

[`DependencyPropertyDescriptor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291201/dependencyproperty-from-string/6291485#6291485) is not available in UWP.

Here seems to be the same question, however, it is not possible to use it in UWP.
[Getting the attached property "Canvas.Left"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535952/getting-the-attached-property-canvas-left)

Comment: reflection? cant you just do `TextBlock.Text`?

Comment: FYI attached properties why they are called attached properties after all? because other controls can use that property but that property does not belong to the control itself. for instance `TextBlock` does not have `Grid.Row` property, the fact is that `Grid` has attached property `Row` provided for other controls so other controls can use that property.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6291485/424129 -- `GetValue()`, `SetValue()`, same difference. Pass them the `DependencyProperty`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I am aware of using `TextBlock.Text`, but question is about accessing attached properties from string.

Comment: At the very least, you can use reflection to retrieve the field representing the attached property from the class that owns it (e.g. `Grid`, when dealing with `Row` or `Column`...you will need to know that class, obviously). Have you tried the WPF-based technique in the answer @Ed mentioned? What _have_ you tried? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've already tried and explain what _specifically_ you're having trouble with. Your question is too broad as it stands now. Most likely is a duplicate of some other, but without narrowing it, not even possible to know which other

Comment: @PeterDuniho `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` is not available in UWP. My question could be a duplicate of following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535952/getting-the-attached-property-canvas-left), nevertheless, it is not possible do it the same way in UWP. However, I like what you wrote in your first sentence, I think that approach will be enough for my purpose. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.